# Filtering resolved issues where there is both an unreleased and a released version set

Tags: jira

In our Jira issue tracker (hosted by Atlassian) we have many issues that have multiple fixVersions. Some of these are unreleased versions and others are released. The various versions come from different workflows across teams, and isn't something I can change.

What I'm looking for is a JQL filter query for the Work Sub-Filter on the board configuration page that excludes any issue that has at least one fixVersion that is released.

The default filter

```
fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY
```

leaves the issue on the board as long as at least one of the fixVersions is unreleased.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY) 
and (fixVersion not in releasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY)
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: So basically, this is the same as `fixVersion not in releasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY`. Steps: `(fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY) and (fixVersion not in releasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY)` which can be simplified to: `fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() and fixVersion not in releasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY` which can be simplified to `fixVersion not in releasedVersions() or fixVersion is EMPTY`